# Apex error: Unexpected token: Map

Tags: apex, map, field-mapping

I am trying to get recordType Id's without using a SOQL query (source [codespokes.com: how-to-get-record-type-id-without-soql](http://www.codespokes.com/2013/01/how-to-get-record-type-id-without-soql.html)):

```
// User need to pass two parameters SObject Type & 
// RecordType Label ( not Record Type Developer Name)
public static Id getRecordTypeId(String ObjectType, String RecordTypeLabel)
{ 
  SObject OBJ;
  // Describing Schema
  Schema.SObjectType Res = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(ObjectType);
  if (Res != null)
  {
    
      OBJ = Res.newSObject();
      // Describing Object 
      Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DesRes = OBJ.getSObjectType().getDescribe(); 
      
      if(DesRes != null){
        // Get a map of fields for the SObject Save error: unexpected token: 'map'
        map <string schema.recordtypeinfo="schema.recordtypeinfo"> RecordTypeMap = DesRes.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        if (RecordTypeMap != null) 
            {
            Schema.RecordTypeInfo RecordTypeRes = RecordTypeMap.get(RecordTypeLabel);
            if (RecordTypeRes != null) {
                return RecordTypeRes.getRecordTypeId();
                }
              }
           }
        }
     return null;
    }
```

But on the line `map <string schema.recordtypeinfo="schema.recordtypeinfo"> RecordTypeMap = DesRes.getRecordTypeInfosByName();` I am getting an error **Unexpected token: 'map'**

What have I done wrong, I've tried re-writing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change that to this:

```
Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> RecordTypeMap = DesRes.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
```